# Encrypting multiple groups of data with separate keys in a single encrypted column

Tags: aes, keys, multiparty-computation, brute-force-attack, multiple-encryption

I will write this question using a database example, but please note this detail may be irrelevant.

Let's say I have data belonging to N clients stored in a single column of a database table. Each client has their own AES key used to encrypt/decrypt their own data.

In this setting, I have the understanding that if someone gets a copy of all values in the database, then brute-force attacks would actually become *easier* than if I had used just one single key to encrypt the entire column instead of this one-key-per-client approach.

If I had used just a single key for the entire data, the attacker would need to find that one key that would correctly decrypt all of the data. However, if one different key has been used to encrypt each of those N partitions, then time for finding at least one key that would decrypt at least one of these partitions would be reduced by a factor of N, since each candidate key being tested during a brute-force attack could match any of the N keys instead of having to match just one.

In this situation, it seems all that I have done was to reduce the search surface for finding a valid key from X to X/N.

**Edited for clarification** -
All the above mentioned, my question is: Is having a single column with data encrypted according to different keys could possibly make brute-forcing the data easier?

If yes, what would be a suitable approach to overcome this, i.e., for encrypting different groups of data using separate keys without reducing the difficulty of brute-forcing individual keys?

Comment: It makes no sense. 1) For smb. who gets a copy of the data it will be impossible to brute-force even a single key, thus your approach makes no sense. 2) For smb. who attacks your software that works with decrypted data (database application itself or client application), there will be no difference because the data at that moment are already decrypted, thus your approach again makes no sense.

Comment: You mean, the approach of having separate keys per client does not make sense, or the impression that this will make brute-forcing easier doesn't make sense? Sorry I think I badly worded the question

Comment: Think what attack are you going to protect your data from. A) From brute-forcing? If you trust AES, then you know that it would need 2^128 ~= 10^38 = 100 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 operations. Even the computer power of the whole planet during millions of years will not be sufficient for single key. Thus having more than one key adds complexity but does not add security.

Comment: B) Don't you trust AES? Then it makes no sense to use it at all. If you believe AES is broken, then you should accept that for an attacker there is no difference to break 1 key or to break 1 000 000 keys. C) If you trust AES, but you want to protect from stealing the keys? For an attacker there would be no difference between stealing 1 key or 1 000 000 keys. Thus in any scenario I see no reason in having more than one key.

Comment: Thanks, I see, brute-forcing would not be the concern here. But talking about attacks, what about D) Certain fields need to be equality-searchable within a client (but not across clients), so some fields would be using deterministic encryption. If an attacker hacks/impersonates one of the clients, enters arbitrary values in the database through the application, then obtains a copy of the database data, even though the database data would be encrypted, wouldn't he/she be able to know where those values also happen in the data of other clients? Wouldn't separate keys help mitigate this issue?

Comment: To search on some field, you create an index. To create an index, you need all values without encryption. If you are going to search by a fulls scan and decrypting each single value, then yes, a particular request will match only records that were correctly decrypted. But each such request may take many minutes or hours, depending how big your data sets are. And the main protection measure is not encryption, but proper implementation of authorization logic.

Comment: I am referring to the case of deterministic encryption. In this case, both search and indexing can be performed using only the ciphertexts.

Comment: You cannot index encrypted values. For search your will have to do the full scan. Example: From 1 000 000 records, let say orders, you want to select those 1 000 orders where total sum was between $50 and $60. With unencrypted data an index would allow to find all 1 000 records almost immediately, it would cost you merely 20 operations, because log2(1 000 000) = 20. But with encrypted data you cannot index anything and you will have to check **every** of 1 000 000 records. Thus your request will take 50 000 (!) more time compared to the unencrypted indexed data (1 000 000 / 20 = 50 000).

Comment: Only you know if your users can accept that your application works 50 000 slower than similar application of other service providers.